# Excel Macro - If cell.value has 'this text' Then

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write code to find a set of text (e.g. Vice President, President, Director... etc) and place VP, Executive or Director respectively in the cell to the right.  After making several attempts, I am seeking help.

```
Sub Enter_Job_Function()


'
' This Macro is designed to take keywords in the job title column and place       
' the approperate Job Function in the approperate column.
'

Dim result As String


Range("O2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
' Cells.Find(What:="Vice President", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
 '   , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
'    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("O2").Value, "Vice President") > 0,_
Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value "VP"

End Sub
```

Comment: In which column is your data stored? Column O?

Comment: @JLILI Aman Yes, Column O.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheet1.Cells.Find("Vice President").Offset(0, 1) = "VP"
Sheet1.Cells.Find("President", , , xlWhole).Offset(0, 1) = "Executive"
Sheet1.Cells.Find("Director").Offset(0, 1) = "Director"
On Error Goto 0
```

Not sure of your requirements but this will find all the first instances of the words you enumerated and place the equivalent tag on the cell next to it. HTH.

Comment: Hi @L42
Thanks for this, I am trying to find all of the instances of the words I mentioned above.  I will try to get a loop going, however any help with that would be great.